# Access secret from Azure Key Vault from browser (node.js with Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a Vue single-page application (not deployed as of yet), that calls an Azure function to get some data. The Azure function is has admin level security, and so I need the master key to call it.

Because I don't want the master key hardcoded into my JavaScript, I put it into an Azure Key Vault as a secret. Now, I'm having trouble accessing it, so that I can run my Azure function.

Every tutorial I've found online doesn't help. I even found an npm module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets) that allows one to access secrets from the key vault - however using this module in the browser (where my code will run) is deemed unsafe.

If it's relevant, I'd like to be able to access the key vault from my website *locally* when testing it, but also when I deploy it (I don't know where at the moment, but I'll most likely deploy my website on Azure). Also, I'd prefer not having to write server-side code, as I'm writing an SPA

So... how can I access a secret in my key vault from a vue website (aka JavaScript that's run in the browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main blocker to what you are trying to achieve is lack of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) support at the service level. Because Azure Key Vault does not provide CORS configuration your requests to Key Vault will fail when run in the browser.

But you do have a few options:

1. A server-side component which can act as an intermediary and allows you to configure CORS policies for your application. Because CORS is a browser restriction, a server-side application will be able to communicate with Azure Key Vault without configuring CORS.
2. You can use [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/api-management/#overview) to act as a bridge between your client-side application and Azure Key Vault. Because Azure API Management supports CORS it will be able to communicate with Azure Key Vault.

You might be interested in [this documentation and sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/samples/cors/ts) I created demonstrating the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve looked into the API Management thing, and I guess I have two major questions. 1) which is recommended/the best? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? 2) how could I apply API Management to my needs? I’ve looked into it, but the docs mainly talk about the back-end

Comment: I want to add, I looked at your example and it's great! I'm just concerned that you use environment variables (to get the api name), and I'm wondering if it would be safe in production? If somebody found the api name, would they then be able to access my API?

Comment: @jack.py each approach has its own set of benefits. The Azure API Management route provides a lot of flexibility out of the box and requires no deployments, no custom code, etc. 

The custom server approach provides a lot of control, customization, and is likely to be well-documented as it uses common architecture. 

With that said, my _personal_ preference is to deploy a lightweight server as I always end up needing it for more than just bypassing CORS. You can play around with both and see what you like :)

Comment: Thank you for the compliment on the example! I tried to keep it as simple as possible but you're quite right that you'd need to secure the API Management endpoint. You can do that using a combination of CORS policies (only allowing access from your well-known production URI), Azure AD App Registrations, and token authentication.

I am far from a security expert but Azure has a lot of documentation on the subject - https://learn.microsoft.com/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/api-management-security-baseline?toc=/azure/api-management/TOC.json#identity-and-access-control

Answer (score 1):

//Edited after comments

If you dont have server-side code, you basically cannot fetch from KeyVault. As such it would be easier to just use [Azure AD to authorize against your Function directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) and circumvent KeyVault.

Comment: I’m not sure if accessing Key Vault directly from the browser is an option. For this to work, CORS must be configured properly on Key Vault which I believe is not supported (I may be wrong though).

Comment: oh you are right, my bad. Well then I guess you are out of luck without any server side component - or you circumvent KeyVault altogether by using AAD towards your Function